# trying to achieve two way binding between ng-repeate and a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Values of selected row in ng-repeate get populated in a form below it. to accomplish this i am doing a simple thing

```
<p ng-repeat="item in  array" ng-click="SetCurrVariable(item)">
   {{item.ThresholdSet}}
</p>
```

in the controller i have a function

```
  $scope.array = [
        {  ThresholdSet: false },
        { ThresholdSet: false },
        {  ThresholdSet: false }
    ];

  $scope.SetCurrVariable = function (variable) {
        $scope.CurrVariable = variable;
    };
```

form have a check-box that i bind to a property of CurrVariable

```
     <input id="chkThr" type="checkbox" ng-model="CurrVariable.ThresholdSet">
```

i am trying to achieve this behavior that if i click the check-Box in the form. The change gets visible  in ng-repeate like a two way  binding.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RAVXtW3BECg4COBazUiC?p=preview) setup

**Updated with $scope**

Comment: You are missing a lot of code. Where is your array from "item in array"?  The ng-repeat should be in inside of the opening p tag along with the ng-click attribute. Do you have any working code that you can post? It seems like there are a lot of issues to work on before we can get to the two way binding.

Comment: i have updated the question.

Comment: Ok thank you I will see what I can do to help.

Comment: i have setup a plunkr

Comment: you are missing `$scope` in **multiple** areas in your controller.  Try `$scope.SetCurrVariable = function (variable) {
        $scope.CurrVariable = variable;
    };`

Comment: I added it. Realized later. Plunkr is updated.

Comment: also, your `input` is outside your `div` that the `ng-controller` manages.

Comment: yes that was the issue

Comment: i can mark it as an answer

Comment: I'm glad that this solved your issue, but I still voted to close the question as off topic due to typographical errors.  These kind of questions are rarely helpful to others in the future, especially since the comments were used to actively troubleshoot and modify the question itself over time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.SetCurrVariable = function (variable) {
    $scope.CurrVariable = variable;
};
```

Use this code in your controller, then the two-way binding should work